# most efficient way to store and query geospatial data with Spring and Postgis

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, geojson, topojson

I'm currently working on an application in form of a map that displays coverage levels of a service in a country. There is Level3 = great coverage, Level2 = good coverage and Level1 = low coverage.
I get data in form of geojson files describing polygon and multipolygon coordinates and I currently use ogr2ogr.java tool to import them in Postgres.
And when the frontend app makes a request with latitude and longitude parameters for the cardinal points on the backend API (a spring rest controller) I want to query the database to get the coverage levels coresponding to the area determined by the coordinates parameters sent by frontend, and return in most efficient way the result in format geojson or topojson.

Currently, for my data, geojson takes even 4 MB and 6/7 seconds per request so i thought topojson would be better solution.

I found 3 ways to return topojson from postgis dabatase query:

- convert the geometries in database to topogeometries and then to
  topojson using just postgis functions and java . But this takes lot
  of time.
- convert query result to geojson using postgis functions and java and then convert geojson to topojson using node.js library but this
  solution doesn't seem elegant and easy since java code must call
  javascript/node.js code and get result
- convert query result to shape files using java and then to topojson using ogr2ogr.java but I would like to be able to store the    shape
  files directly in postgres database or in-memory and get    topojson

.

So currently i'm focusing on the last solution with shapefiles and on using topojson but I have not found a solution to store the shape files directly in postgres database or in-memory , just on disk.

So let me know if you have an idea about this or other efficient solution.

Thanks

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: No because I expect answers from people who tried something similar and found an acceptable solution